# How to remove a css class with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am adding a css class to some asp buttons on `mouseenter` and removing that class on `mouseleave` but i don't see the effect of new class the class which i added on mouse enter is still there.

I m doing something like:

```
 <script src="jquery-1.6.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            // mouse hover
            $("[id^='MangoPager_btn']").mouseenter(mouseenterfunction);
            // mouse leave
            $("[id^='MangoPager_btn']").mouseleave(mouseleavefunction);

        });

        function mouseleavefunction() {

            $(this).removeClass("pagerbtnHover");
            $(this).addClass("buttonclass");        }

        function mouseenterfunction() {

            $(this).addClass("pagerbtnMouseEnter");
        }

    </script>
```

on mouse leave i want to remove `pagerbtnMouseEnter` class and want to attach `buttonclass`.

Comment: i think it'll be overridden when you add another class

Comment: As an aside, you can chain function calls to a jQuery-object, this way you can avoid initializing the same object several times. E.g. `$(this).removeClass(...).addClass(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding a different class than you're removing:

```
$(this).addClass("pagerbtnMouseEnter");

// should be $(this).removeClass('pagerbtnMouseEnter');
$(this).removeClass("pagerbtnHover");
```

Make sure both class names match and you shouldn't have a problem.

On another note, you could clean your JavaScript up a bit by using `hover()` and getting rid of the use of `$(document).ready()`:

```
$(function(){
    $("[id^='MangoPager_btn']").hover(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('pagerbtnMouseEnter');
    });
);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not removing the same class you are adding...

```
$(this).addClass("pagerbtnMouseEnter");
$(this).removeClass("pagerbtnHover");
```

Comment: Thanks Jon Grant it was a silly mistake of mine i just renamed the class name and didn't updated in the function...thank u ..

Answer (score 1):

$(this).removeClass("pagerbtnHover");

$(this).addClass("pagerbtnMouseEnter");

you are removing the wrong class....

Answer (score 1):

Even simpler: use [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover) with a single argument, and [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass).

```
$(function ()
{
    $("[id^='MangoPager_btn']").hover(function ()
    {
        $(this).toggleClass('pagerbtnMouseEnter');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you make all buttons have the `buttonclass` class at all times, and have `pagerBtnHover` override the necessary styles in button class. Get rid of the `pagerbtnMouseEnter` class. Then, you can do:

```
function mouseleavefunction() {
    $(this).removeClass("pagerbtnHover");
}

function mouseenterfunction() {
    $(this).addClass("pagerbtnHover");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to call the jQuery selector twice, you can chain.

```
$(this).removeClass('pagerbtnMouseEnter').addClass("buttonclass");
```

Also you should stick that retrieved element to a variable if you want to use it somwhere else, instead of calling the same jQuery function to find it again and again.

```
var $this = $(this);

// Use $this from here on...
```